# preg_match_all get text between 2 strings

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I would like to get string between 2 strings.

```
background:url(images/cont-bottom.png) no-repeat;
```

Basically I would like to get all text between `url(` and `)`

Hope somebody can help me. thanks!

Comment: You should first try yourself and post your code here. Then, we'll try to help.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('~[(](.+?)[)]~',$string,$matches);
```

Comment: That includes the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
$css_file = 
   'background:url(images/cont-bottom.png) no-repeat;
    background:url(images/cont-left.png) no-repeat;
    background:url(images/cont-top.png) no-repeat;
    background:url(images/cont-right.png) no-repeat;';

//matches all images inside the css file and loop the results

preg_match_all('/url\((.*?)\)/i', $css_file, $css_images, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($css_images[0]); $i++) {
   echo $css_images[1][$i]."<br>";
}

/*
Outputs:
images/cont-bottom.png
images/cont-left.png
images/cont-top.png
images/cont-right.png
*/    
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`(.*?)` will not continue to a new line to search matches, but `(.*)` will continue to a new line

```
$string = 'background:url(images/cont-bottom.png) no-repeat;';

preg_match_all("#background:url\((.*?)\)#", $string, $match);

echo  $match[1][0];
```

Output:

```
images/cont-bottom.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
/url\s*\([^\)]+\)/
```

Answer (score -2):

try this for this particular situation

```
function getInbetweenStrings($start, $end, $str){
    $matches = array();
    $regex = "/$start(.*)$end/";
    preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

$str = "background:url(images/cont-bottom.png) no-repeat;";
$str_arr = getInbetweenStrings("\(", "\)", $str);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($str_arr);
```

Comment: It return empty string so it's not a good solution if you're using eg. {START} {STOP} strings as some kind of tags.