# How to generate set of array from string in php

Tags: php, regex

This is my string

**#Jhon: Manager #Mac: Project Manager #Az: Owner**

And I want array something like this

```
$array = ['0' => 'Manager', '1' => 'Project Manager', '2' => 'Owner']
```

I tried this but each time return only 'Manager'

```
$string = '#Jhon: Manager #Mac: Project Manager #Az: Owner';
getText($string, ':', ' #')
public function getText($string, $start, $end)
{
  $pattern = sprintf(
      '/%s(.+?)%s/ims',
      preg_quote($start, '/'), preg_quote($end, '/')
  );

  if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) {
      list(, $match) = $matches;
      echo $match;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using `preg_match_all`. But remeber, owner doesn't have the end character `#`. So only `Manager` and `Project Manager` will be matched

Comment: Functionally related: [preg match to get text after @ symbol and before next space using php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25914018/2943403)

Comment: Related: [preg_match_all get text between 2 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6976707/2943403) and [Get string between every two certain characters with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53721443/2943403)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may `preg_split` the contents and use the following solution:

```
$re = '/\s*#[^:]+:\s*/';
$str = '#Jhon: Manager #Mac: Project Manager #Az: Owner';
$res = preg_split($re, $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($res);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/N7gRNK) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P0s10e/3).

**Pattern details**:

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `#` -  a literal `#` symbol
- `[^:]+` to match 1+ chars other than `:`
- `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

Note that `-1` in the [`preg_split` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) is the `$limit` argument telling PHP to split any amount of times (as necessary) and `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` will discard all empty matches (this one may be removed if you need to keep empty matches, that depends on what you need to do further).

Comment: Thanks wiktor.. but when my string is '#Jhon: Manager #Mac@gmail.com: Project Manager #Az: Owner' not working.. sorry for not specify this possibility

Comment: @Komal: But I already wrote - use `[^:\s]+` in that case, use [`\s*#[^:\s]+:\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/P0s10e/2). I removed the `\w`-based regex variation.

Comment: One more possibility is space between name  '#Jhon M: Manager #Mac@gmail.com: Project Manager #Az: Owner'

Comment: @Komal: Then how can you differentiate `#` as the starting point of the key and a `#` that is part of the value?

Comment: Ok, remove `\s` from the `[^:\s]+`. See [**this demo**](https://regex101.com/r/P0s10e/3).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143507/discussion-between-komal-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 6):

Here we are using `preg_match` to achieve desired output.

**Regex:** `#\w+\s*\:\s*\K[\w\s]+`

> **1.** `#\w+\s*\:\s*\K` this will match `#` then `words` then `spaces` and then `:` `\K` will reset current match.
>
> **2.** `[\w\s]+` This will match your desired output which contains `words` and `spaces`.

**Solution 1:**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string="#Jhon: Manager #Mac: Project Manager #Az: Owner";
preg_match_all("/#\w+\s*\:\s*\K[\w\s]+/", $string,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Manager 
            [1] => Project Manager 
            [2] => Owner
        )

)
```

---

Here we are using `array_map` and `explode` to achieve desired out. Here we first we are `exploding` string on `#` and then exploding its array values on `:` and pushing its `first` index in the resultant array.

**Solution 2:**

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/787827)

```
<?php

$string="#Jhon: Manager #Mac: Project Manager #Az: Owner";
$result=  array_map(function($value){
    return trim(explode(":",$value)[1]);
}, array_filter(explode("#", $string)));
print_r(array_filter($result));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Manager
    [2] => Project Manager
    [3] => Owner
)
```

Comment: @SahilGulati 2nd Gives me error Undefined offset: 1, and first is working but not worked when my string is '#Jhon: Manager #Mac@gmail.com: Project Manager #Az: Owner' sorry for not specifing this possibility..

Comment: @Komal Hope this will help you out.. I have updated my post for that for demo you can check this https://eval.in/787827

Comment: This way is indeed better since the pattern starts with a literal character. You can remove the eventual trailing spaces using: https://regex101.com/r/tgjssx/1

Comment: @Casimir just for my safe side i added this so that OP will not face any further issues with other string input which may contain spaces.. Anyways thanks sir...:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split the string by char. After that just replace the elements of new array with [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$string = '#Jhon: Manager #Mac: Project Manager #Az: Owner';
$res = explode("#", $string);
$result = array();
for($i = 1; $i < count($res); $i++)  {
    $result[] = preg_replace("/(^[A-Z][a-z]*: )/", "", $res[$i]);
}
```