# Get string between every two certain characters with PHP

Tags: php

I have string like this:

```
The time is over. # its mean I'm need to die. Please help me. # Ghost. I am here alone. Sorry. # help yourself.
```

I want to get the text between every # and dot (.)
so I use this:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$parsed = trim(get_string_between($url, '#', '.'));
echo $parsed;
```

The problem its that the function return only the first example match to my query. I dont have any idea to do its for **every** query like I choose.

in this example string its need to return this:

```
its mean I'm need to die

Ghost

help yourself
```

**Edit for @Nick Answer**

My real string is this:

```
Text Text Text # Very good. #:* after this come example. Text Text Text #Very good number 2.
```

Your code also return me the string after `#:*`, I need only what seems like these examples:
`# Text Text.` **or** `#Text Text.`

in the given example I need to get this texts:

`Very good` and `Very good number 2`

Comment: Your problem description is really unclear. Between every `#` and `.`? That means your matches in your first example string would be `(space)` and `its mean I'm need to die` is that correct?

Comment: Do you want the second result to be " Ghost" or " Ghost. I am here alone"? Because even with a loop of your function through the text, you'll still have an issue where the desired text has periods inside of it. Maybe the better aproach is finding the text between `#` and a linebreak?

Comment: no, I just edit now the question to make it clear. @Xatenev see edit

Comment: @JaredC no because the query text can be in the middle of text.

Comment: So you copied the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/how-to-get-a-substring-between-two-strings-in-php) without trying anything yourself and asked help from people? I call this being lazy.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

Based on OPs edit, the regex needs to be changed to use a positive lookahead for either a space or an alphabetic character immediately after the `#` i.e.

```
/#(?=[ A-Za-z])\s*([^.]*)\./
```

To use the text from the edit:

```
$string = "Text Text Text # Very good. #:* after this come example. Text Text Text #Very good number 2.";
preg_match_all('/#(?=[ A-Za-z])\s*([^.]*)\./', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Very good
    [1] => Very good number 2
)
```

Updated [demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/OTEQOG81236)

**Original Answer**

You can use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to get the results you want. This regex looks for a set of characters between a `#` and a `.`, stripping any whitespace on either end by using a non-greedy capturing group and `\s*` on either side of the capturing group:

```
$string = "The time is over. # its mean I'm need to die .
Please help me. # Ghost. I am here alone.
Sorry. # help yourself.";
preg_match_all('/#\s*([^.]*?)\s*\./', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => its mean I'm need to die
    [1] => Ghost
    [2] => help yourself
)
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/HLHIP73865)

Comment: Work perfectly but only in the first because my string its different from my given example. I edit the post now.

Comment: @Ben so there can only be a space or an alphabetic character after the `#`, is that correct?

Comment: yes, exacly. for example: `# text.` or `#text.` but not `#:* text.`

Comment: @Ben I think my edited answer will solve that problem.

Comment: its possible to make a foreach on ```$matches[1]```?

Comment: @Ben definitely. It's an array so you can use foreach on it.

Comment: you can give an example how to create foreach on specific row in array? (`$matches[1]`)

Comment: @Ben `foreach ($matches[1] as $text) { echo $text; }`

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [explode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php), [substr](http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php), and [strpos](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php) can do it:

Split the string by `#`, then get the string between `#` and the first `.` by using `substr` and `strpos`.

```
<?php

$examples = [
    'The time is over. # its mean I\'m need to die.',
'Please help me. # Ghost. I am here alone.',
'Sorry. # help yourself.'];

foreach($examples as $example) {
    $exploded = explode('#', $example);
    $substr = trim(substr($exploded[1], 0, strpos($exploded[1], '.')));
    var_dump($substr);
}
```

In a function for one specific string:

```
$test = parseString('Sorry. # help yourself.');
function parseString($string) {
    $exploded = explode('#', $string);
    $substr = trim(substr($exploded[1], 0, strpos($exploded[1], '.')));

    return $substr;
}

var_dump($test);
```

With string input we have to do an additional step that is breaking by `\n` before:

```
$stringExample = "The time is over. # its mean I'm need to die.
Please help me. # Ghost. I am here alone.
Sorry. # help yourself.";


$test2 = parseString2($stringExample);
function parseString2($string) {
    $result = [];
    $array = explode("\n", $string);

    foreach($array as $a) {
        $exploded = explode('#', $a);
        $substr = trim(substr($exploded[1], 0, strpos($exploded[1], '.')));    
        $result[] = $substr;
    }

    return $result;
}
var_dump($test2);
```

For string input without linebreaks, a little parser could look like:

```
$stringExample2 = "The time is over. # its mean I'm need to die. Please help me. # Ghost. I am here alone. Sorry. # help yourself.";


var_dump(parseString3($stringExample2));
function parseString3($stringExample)
{
    $result2 = [];

    $startBlock = false;

    $block = 0;
    foreach (str_split($stringExample) as $char) {
        if ($char === '#') { // Start block
            $startBlock = true;
        } else if ($startBlock && $char === '.') { // End block
            $result2[$block] = trim($result2[$block]); // Remove unnecessary whitespace
            $block++;
            $startBlock = false;
        } else if ($startBlock) { // Character to append to block
            if (!isset($result2[$block])) { // We have to check if the block has been started already and if not, create it as an empty string because otherwise we would get a notice when trying to append our character to it.
                $result2[$block] = '';
            }
            $result2[$block] .= $char;
        }

    }
    return $result2;
}
```

*If you use any of this code, please make sure to actually understand what is happening and use adequate variable names, these are just small example snippets.*

*All examples with their output can be found in the 3v4l link below*

https://3v4l.org/k3TXM

Comment: It's not an array of strings, it's only a string

Comment: @executable ? Im iterating through the examples from OP. I will add an example with a specific string, I don't see why its needed though

Comment: @Xatenev thank you very much for helping. as he said, my problem its with string without array - I try what you send in the past.

Comment: @executable Oh, I get what you meant.

Comment: @Xatenev sorry but as I say in the question, my problem its with multiple querys like my example. I mean - more than 1.

Comment: @Ben is the text seperated by linebreaks? I.e. `\n`?

Comment: no the text its simple text (long text without line breaks)

Comment: @Xatenev see my last comment here.

Comment: @Ben added a small parser that handles the case of no linebreaks.